# How to disable browser caching of CSS, JS files in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, assets, browser-cache

I am developing in CakePHP 3.5.* in localhost in Windows. Is there a way to load most recent versions of assets such as CSS, Javascript while developing? I remember there is something like timestamp settings but could not figure that out while looking at the documentation.

Comment: you can temporally reduce the cache size of browser to 0 mb

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. It is:

```
'Asset' => [
    'timestamp' => true,
],
```

There is a settings in the config/app.php file, which by default is:

```
'Asset' => [
    // 'timestamp' => true,
],
```

A comment just above it says,

> Apply timestamps with the last modified time to static assets (js,
>   css, images). Will append a querystring parameter containing the time
>   the file was modified. This is useful for busting browser caches.
>
> Set to true to apply timestamps when debug is true. Set to 'force' to
>   always enable timestamping regardless of debug value.

Which means, to force most recent assets it will look like:

```
'Asset' => [
    'timestamp' => true,
],
```

In another answer i found it answered as:

```
'Asset' => [
    'force'
],
```

But it does not work in CakePHP 3.5.*. May be it worked in earlier versions.

Comment: The correct syntax would be `'timestamp' => 'force'`